# Displaying different currencies for a single product

Tags: price, magento-1.9

I want different base price for different currency, by default Magento converts the price based on currency ratio what we provide.
I have such requirements that I want to enter different price for different currency for each product.

Example 
Product A  10 Euro, 5 Dollar, 100 Rupees
Product B  15 Euro, 9 Dollar, 500 Rupees

How to achieve this.

Please help.

Thank You

Answer (score 3):

First load currency loaded currency rates the multiple with product price

```
 $Product=Mage:getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
        $currencyModel = Mage::getModel('directory/currency');
        $currencies = $currencyModel->getConfigAllowCurrencies();
 $baseCurrencyCode = Mage::app()->getStore()->getBaseCurrencyCode();

        $defaultCurrencies = $currencyModel->getConfigBaseCurrencies();

                $rates=$currencyModel->getCurrencyRates($defaultCurrencies, $currencies);


                foreach($rates[$baseCurrencyCode] as $key=>$value  ) {
                    echo $key."-";
                    echo $price=$value*$Product->getPrice();
                    echo "<br/>";

                }
```

Comment: I'd add a colon after Mage in 1st line :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the [Product Base Currency](http://innoexts.com/promotion/product-base-currency/) extension?

It allows setting different base price for different currency on a per product basis.

Comment: Yeah, I checked it. It isn't free and my company doesn't want to pay for that extension, so was searching for a free extension which could achieve this