# Display different currency depending on product, Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, multicurrency

I manage a store and we have products from multiple vendors. Some vendors are selling in USD, some in EURO, so in my store, for some products I will need to display the price in EURO and for others I will need to display it in USD.

I have one store with one view and the base currency is RON, our local currency as our customers want to be invoiced and pay in their currency. I did the multi currency set up, selected the 3 currencies that I need, set the currency symbols and rates, but I don't know how to show different currencies in the frontend as well.

Is there a way to select the currency of display for each product when I am adding it? I was thinking that multiple views would solve this issue, but I am not sure if this would work. I am using Magento ver. 1.9.4.2.

If you have any suggestions, they are more than welcomed. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it with multiple view but you must think about the business logic behind it also such as relations between shipping-language-currency, you can see the example of https://1people.com (Indonesian Rupiah) , https://1people.com/dk (Danish Kron) , and https://1people.com/uk (Great Britain Pundsterling). Note: it's in Magento 2.2

But, maybe you can try with this code modification : https://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-add-currency-selector-to-magentos-header/

Or this free extension may help : https://marketplace.magento.com/meetanshi-magento-currency-switcher.html (although last supporrted is version 1.9.3 , maybe you can give it a try in the staging server)

Comment: Thank you for your response. What we need actually is having one view and the possibility to display on the same view both EURO and USD, because some of our products are merchandised in EURO and some in USD by our vendors, and that is how we want to display them on our catalog as well. Base currency will be the same, which is RON, in all cases because our customers want to be billed in our local currency. We are willing to pay for an extension or for someone to help us, but so far I couldn't find neither one. Thank you again for your response and for your suggestions!

Comment: Sorry, I have to re-read your question to be more understand with the case. I want to confirm something though, do you mean like this case : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/24551/displaying-different-currencies-for-a-single-product

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but is not the same situation. What I want to achieve is: 1 view, 1 base currency - RON, hardware product - base currency RON, display price 500 USD, software product - base currency RON, display price 500 EURO. The reason for that is because the recommended price from the vendor is listed in USD and the recommended price for software is in EURO. I don't want to enter different price as all prices are converted on the currency rate we provide. What I want is just to display the prices on different currency. Hope this clarifies your question. Thank you!

Comment: Basically I want to display 2 currencies on the same store, but without having the currency selector on the front end, but rather in the backend, which would enable me to choose which currency to display on each product. So I would have some products listed with USD prices and other listed with EURO prices on the same store.